# Unable to resolve module in react-viro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run this app and I get the following error!
https://github.com/vnovick/pile-blocks-ar

I checked the proper asset import instruction from here https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/importing-assets
everything seems legit but I keep getting the error!

===

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./res/tetris/blocks_1.vrx` from `/Users/###/pile-blocks-ar-master/js/GameSceneAR.js`: The module `./res/tetris/blocks_1.vrx` could not be found from `/Users/###/pile-blocks-ar-master/js/GameSceneAR.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `/Users/###/pile-blocks-ar-master/js/res/tetris/blocks_1.vrx
  ...

===

I change the versions in package.json to the latest:
"react": "16.6.1",
"react-native": "0.57.7",
"react-viro": "2.13.0"

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add assets support manualy if you have imported ViroAR in existing React-Native app (not created with Viro CLI).

Here's the guide:
https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/importing-assets

If you are using RN > 0.59 then you should discard viro instructions and modify `metro.config.js` file (located in project root) to look something like this:

```
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    assetExts: [
      'obj',
      'mtl',
      'JPG',
      'vrx',
      'hdr',
      'gltf',
      'glb',
      'bin',
      'arobject',
      'png',
    ],
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

***`resolver.assetExts`*** is the key.

Comment: This results in a build error:
Process 'command 'npx'' finished with non-zero exit value 1